# NuGet crashes visual studio 2010, System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crash, nuget

When i try to update my NuGet packages, the visual studio crashes. 
It crashes on the message "Restoring NuGet package EntityFramework 5.0.0"

When i attached another vs to debug it, it throws an exception System.ExecutionEngineException.

I'm using NuGet in version 2.8.60318.667, vs2010 sp1.
I tried reinstalling NuGet but it didn't help.

Do you know what can be the cause?

Comment: Just google it, [this appears to be an exact match](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2012/09/25/ExecutionEngineExceptionThrownWhenUsingCodeContracts/).

Comment: Actually it didn't help. I tried to find the solution in google but failed.